# clang & stdc++: potential c++ future/promise bug

Tags: c++, c++11, promise, future

Just played a bit on Mac OS Sierra (10.12.6) with Clang and stdc++

```
$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Here is stated:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/~promise:

> Abandons the shared state:
>
> - if the shared state is ready, releases it.
> - if the shared state is not ready, stores an exception object of type std::future_error with an error condition std::future_errc::broken_promise, makes the shared state ready and releases it.

IMO, it's pretty obvious that if promise is destroyed future::get() must raise and exception and cancel the waiting. This C++ code blocks and no exception is raised:

```
auto p = std::make_unique<std::promise<std::string>>();

// getting a future and deleting the promise should make that 
// future ready and raise an exception
{
  auto f = p->get_future();

  p.release();
  f.get();  // must raise an exception
}
```

Did I just find a bug in stdc++ lib implementation?

*Resolved:* As G.M. pointed out I mixed up `release` with `reset`.

Comment: [`std::unique_ptr::release`](http:///home/gmaitlan/www/cppreference-doc-20151129/reference/en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release.html) *doesn't* free the managed item.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for that! I typed `re` and auto-complete did the rest... and I did not pay attention that the function name should be `reset`. If you put it as an answer. I will accept it.